# link não é chamado

Tags: jquery

Tenho um codigo jQuery que gera uma div ele funciona tranquilamente, nele tenho o seguinte trecho

```
div += "<p>Coloque o seu <a class='text-orange' id='link_new_ad'>veículo a disposição</a>!</p>";
```

depois eu adiciono essa div e ela aparece na tela certinho, porem meu problema é que queria chamar o evento de outro botão ao clicar nesse link

```
$("#link_new_ad").click(function (){
    alert('teste');
    $("#bundle_ad_submit").trigger('click');
});
```

porem quando clico no link nada acontece, seu colocar o link no html em vez de colocar pelo append(div) ele chama o evento.

Alguem sabe o que ta acontecendo, e melhor como concertar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso ocorre pois no você está atribuindo o evento `click` ao elemento antes de ele existir no HTML.

Como solução você deve criar o evento do click logo após adicionar a div ao HTML.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var html = "<p>Coloque o seu <a class='text-orange' id='link_new_ad'>veículo a disposição</a>!</p>";
  $('body').html(html);
  //Após adicionar no HTML atribua o evento ao link.
  $("#link_new_ad").click(function() {
    console.log('teste');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Mas então adiciono a div em uma função apos uma chamada assincrona ajax. Você ta dizendo para adicionar o evento do click  dentro dessa função?

Comment: Pode crer deu certo, valeu cara vou por sua resposta como a certa.

Comment: Isso mesmo. Tentou utilizando o `on`citado pelo @RodrigoMello?

Comment: tentei mas não funcionou, mas ai quando coloquei a chamada dentro da função ai funcionou.

Comment: @MarciusLeandro No teu caso acho melhor utilizar o `on` da maneira citada pelo @TobyMosque

Answer (score 4):

Use `$(seuelemento).on("click", function() {})`

Isso ocorre porque o DOM já foi carregado, você precisa do evento `ON` para ficar ouvindo as mudanças da página.

Comment: mano pode crer o que tu disse, mas por algum motivo não funcionou a respoda @pedro-camara-junior funcionou.

Comment: Rodrigo, fiz um teste com o `on`diretamente no console do navegador mas não consegui fazer funcionar, consegue postar um exemplo talvez?

Comment: @Rodrigo, você está aplicando o evento `on()` em um elemento que ainda não existe, isto não vai monitorar a inclusão do mesmo.

Comment: Há outra sintaxe, tente $('body').on("click", "seuelemento", function() {})

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Usar seu JS antes ou depois do body também pode influenciar... É recomendado usar JS antes de fechar fechar o body.

Comment: @RodrigoMello, isto era uma recomendação dada pelo Yahoo nos primórdios da internet. hoje é interresante usar [<script src="file.js" defer />](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/defer/)

Answer (score 1):

Amigão, vc pode chamar o metodo .click() direto, não precisa do trigger.

```
$("#link_new_ad").click(function(){
    alert('teste');
    $("#bundle_ad_submit").click();
});
```

Se nao funcionar, verifica se o $("#bundle_ad_submit") existe mesmo, se ele esta conseguindo achar esse objeto e se tem evento atachado nele.

Answer (score 1):

Como o @PedroCamaraJunior apontou, você está tentando associar um evento antes que ele exista, neste caso o ideal é usar o metódo `on()` em algum parente mais próximo deste elemento e passar um seletor deste elemento como parâmetro.

Abaixo segue um pequeno exemplo de como adicionar conteúdo dinamicamente a pagina e não ter problemas com o bind dos eventos.

```js
var tmplCarro = document.getElementById("tmplCarro").content;
var container = $("#container");
var addCarro = $("#addCarro");

addCarro.on("click", function () {
  var carro = $(document.importNode(tmplCarro, true));
  container.append(carro);
});

container.on("click", ".enviar", function (event) {
  var enviar = $(this);
  var linha = enviar.parent(".linha");
  var carro = $(".carro", linha);
  alert("Enviando Carro: " + carro.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<template id="tmplCarro">
  <div class="linha">
    <label> Carro:
      <input class="carro" type="text" />
    </label>
    <input class="enviar" type="button" value="Enviar" />
  </div>
</template>

<input id="addCarro" type="button" value="Adicionar Carro" />
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Você até pode usar  `$(document).on("click", #link_new_ad", function () { ... })` que irá funcionar, porém o recomendado é utilizar o `parent` mais próximo ao invés de `document`

Comment: Assim funcionou utlizando o `on`. +1

Answer (score 0):

Eu utilizaria o seguinte trecho:

```
$("#link_new_ad").on('click', '#bundle_ad_submit', function()
{
     alert('teste');
})
```

Por que assim o evento on, "ouviria" o DOM e veria quando ele fosse carregado.